# Simple PHP IF/ELSE code not working properly with html markup

Tags: php, html

I have started to learn some basic PHP. So far everything worked perfectly until I tried to run some IF/ELSE statements embedded into the markup as you can see in the snipet bellow:

```html
<?php 
$msg = 0;
echo $msg;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php if ($msg = 5){ ?>
        <h1>5</h1>
    <?php } elseif ($msg = 0) { ?>
        <h1> 0 </h1>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <h1>Whatever</h1>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is always the first if statement, even if it doesn't meet the condition. In this case the result is:

0

**5**

Tried everything I knew and searched a lot without any results. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: YOU missed `=` in your if condition. it should be `==`.

Comment: Also, if you are interested to know if the type is correct, rather than just the value after type [juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), then use `===`

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple syntax error, it needs to be:

```
<?php 
$msg = 0;
echo $msg;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php if ($msg == 5){ ?>
        <h1>5</h1>
    <?php } elseif ($msg == 0) { ?>
        <h1> 0 </h1>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <h1>Whatever</h1>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice the `==` which compares things vs. `=` which sets things.

Answer (score 1):

The `=` sign is for assignment; in order to do a comparison you need to use `==`:

```
<?php if ($msg == 5){ ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the condition -> ($msg = 5)
It should be ==
($msg == 5) instead of ($msg = 5).

When you are comparing two values you need to use double equal sign not single. 
Single means you are assigning value to the variable.

Don'g give up!!

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, we normally just comment on a typo and close the question. They are almost never any use to others

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php 
$msg = 0;
echo $msg;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php if ($msg == 5){ ?>
        <h1>5</h1>
    <?php } elseif ($msg == 0) { ?>
        <h1> 0 </h1>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <h1>Whatever</h1>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include a bit of explanation. Especially on the difference between your code and Jo.joe's.